# Minimum one element from the array exist in another array

Tags: sql, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to check if minumum one element from an array exists in another array. Here is the SQL code for reference:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION is_array_in_array(subset ARRAY<string>, main ARRAY<string>)
AS ((SELECT min(a in UNNEST(main)) FROM UNNEST(subset) as a));
```

What would be the best implementation in PySpark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether the arrays overlap ([docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_overlap)):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('is_array_in_array', F.arrays_overlap('subset_col', 'main_col'))
```